# Multiple Pivot based on single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

Please Consider this Tables:

```
Id     Year     Month      Type      Value      IsUpdate
---------------------------------------------------------
1      2011      1          T1       1000           0  
2      2012      1          T1       2000           0   
3      2011      1          T2       5000           1       
4      2012      1          T2       500            0         
5      2011      1          T3       11000          1      
6      2012      1          T3       800            1
```

I want to create this result :

```
Year   Month    T1_Value    T1_IsUpdate     T2_Value    T2_IsUpdate     T3_Value    T3_IsUpdate
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2011     1       1000            0           5000            1           11000           1
2012     1       2000            0           500             0           800             1
```

Is It possible to create this using `PIVOT`?

Thanks

Comment: You could do this with a Dynamic Pivot or  aDynamic CrossTab.

Answer (score 0):

This is done using a dynamic cross tab. For reference: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

```
CREATE TABLE Temp(
    ID          INT,
    [Year]      INT,
    [Month]     INT,
    [Type]      VARCHAR(5),
    Value       INT,
    IsUpdate    BIT
)
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES
(1, 2011, 1, 'T1', 1000, 0),
(2, 2012, 1, 'T1', 2000, 0),
(3, 2011, 1, 'T2', 5000, 1),
(4, 2012, 1, 'T2', 500, 0),
(5, 2011, 1, 'T3', 11000, 1),
(6, 2012, 1, 'T3', 800, 1);

DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql2 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql3 VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 = 
'SELECT
     [Year]
    ,[Month]'
+ CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = ''' + [Type] + ''' THEN Value END) AS [' + [Type] + '_Value]' + CHAR(10) +
'   ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = ''' + [Type] + ''' THEN CAST(IsUpdate AS INT) END) AS [' + [Type] + '_IsUpdate]' + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT [Type] FROM Temp
)t
ORDER BY [Type]

SELECT @sql3 = 
'FROM Temp
GROUP BY [Year], [Month]
ORDER BY [Year], [Month]'

PRINT(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)

DROP TABLE Temp
```

**RESULT**

```
Year        Month       T1_Value    T1_IsUpdate T2_Value    T2_IsUpdate T3_Value    T3_IsUpdate
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2011        1           1000        0           5000        1           11000       1
2012        1           2000        0           500         0           800         1
```